# What's the goal of an ESPP for the employer?

Tags: compensation

Some employers have an [employee stock purchase plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employee_stock_purchase_plan), this typically allows employees to buffer some percentage of their salary for a number of months and then convert that money to shares at some discount, either from the current price or from `min(current_price, some_past_price)`. I've seen `some_past_price` as the date that the employee enrolled in the program, but it might vary.

This should be a no-brainer for employees, since it's free money, but what's the purpose of offering it for the employer?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Nominate your comment as the answer, because it is.

Comment: I'd be curious to hear what the folks at [money.se] have to say as well. They're basically encouraging people to buy their stock which must have financial benefits for the company.

Comment: Of course, but why do companies choose to offer an ESPP over more salary though? Or more RSUs, if they want to give additional compensation in stock.

Comment: @jgoe My understanding is they aren't giving away free stock, they are giving employees the opportunity to purchase stock, possibly at a discount, directly from the company without having to go through a broker.

Comment: @DavidK that's the literal truth, but the way that it's implemented, everyone does it: it's free money, you're guaranteed a (usually) 15% discount at worst. So it's basically the same as offering a lower salary but more RSUs. At a past company, I've received salary, cash bonus, ESPP, and RSUs separately, so I wonder why they even bother with the ESPP.

Comment: @jgoe At that point trying to understand they difference between the different benefits for the company is probably better suited at [money.se]. I'm not sure we can give you any more answer than what Chris and Mister Positive have already said.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere why did you delete your comment? The conversation reads very strangely now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost every benefit has bone one purpose for the employer and that's to attract and retain quality employees. Each fringe benefit an employer offers will appeal to different people in different ways. Not everyone is attracted by generous insurance and vacations and I've seen many studies that show wages is actually a small (though important) component in retention (so long as the wages are competitive).

ESPP or ESOP are different too in that they literally allow employees to take more ownership of their company's success. There truly is pride in ownership and this can become a direct tangible way that the employee sees personal benefit to company success. As a career contractor, I don't get that "one of us" feel. I can personally see how having some actual stock in a company could help change that.

One thing to remember, almost all employee stock plans offer non-voting stock (in my experience). It still has value like voting stock, but the employer doesn't risk losing control either.

As Joe Strazzere said in a comment, it's all about employee retention. **Turnover is very expensive** and companies that make a genuine effort to retain quality people beyond simple salaries will succeed over ones that don't (when all other factors are equal).

Comment: At least in my experience, everyone I've talked to at an ESPP company sells the stock immediately and either takes the cash or diversifies to e.g. index funds. So they don't really own the stock for a meaningful period of time, it's more of a variable bonus. Same goes for RSUs really.

Comment: @jgoe Well, that's a practical reality. I'm sure the hope is retention. :) What's an RSU?

Comment: It's just when they hand you some shares, usually at specific intervals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_stock

The number of shares is fixed when you are awarded the stock, so you might get 1000 shares over 4 years, 250 shares at the end of each year. You're theoretically motivated to work harder to increase the price, but I'm not sure that really works at the non-exec level - how much influence on the stock price does the average engineer really have?

Answer (score 2):

ESPP 101:

In my companies case, I can buy stock at various times throughout the year for an on average of **15% below stock market price**, so I can make more money ( usually at least 15% ).

NOTE:  Typically with these plans, there is a minimum hold time ( meaning you have to hold the stock for x number of months before selling it off ).

This benefit can be a huge financial gain to the employee over a period of time.  Thus, as Joe said -- employee retention.